# Reading a JSON and output into a HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to read the following JSON and output the result onto a HTML Table.
I just want to get all **EnvID**s on to the HTML Table. I've tried, but it doesn't seem to work.

**Code:**

```
function myFunction(response) {

    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var stringified = JSON.stringify(arr);
    stringified.replace(/"\"/gm, '')
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(stringified);
    var Profile = jsonObject.value[0].PROFILE;
    var jsonProfile = JSON.parse(Profile);

    alert(Profile); //This alert works, and outputs the whole JSON as expected.

    var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    $("#id01").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<jsonProfile.length;i++)
    {
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["EnvId"]+"</td></tr>";
       $("#mytable").append(tr+td1); 
    }   
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<style type="text/css">
    #mainPopup {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Ubuntu, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
</style>
<script src=popup.js></script>
<div id="mainPopup">
<h1>Hello extensionizr!</h1>
</div>
<div id="id01"></div>
```

**JSON:**

```
{  
   "Dashboard":1,
   "Theme":0,
   "Groups":[ somedata ],
   "UserInfo":{ somedata },
   "Shortcuts":[  
      {  
         "Dashboard":1,
         "Index":0,
         "EnvId":"1194"
      },
      {  
         "Dashboard":1,
         "Index":1,
         "EnvId":"2715"
      },
      {  
         "Dashboard":1,
         "Index":2,
         "EnvId":"2714"
      },
      {  
         "Dashboard":1,
         "Index":3,
         "EnvId":"2756"
      }
   ]
}
```

Also I'm a little confused as to why this JSON has different formats, like `"Groups":[ somedata ]` has Square Brackets `[]`, while `"UserInfo":{  },` has the Curly Bracket `{}`

Comment: Can you please provide some sample HTML as well? Also, where do you call this function? Having a full picture will help rule out any possible errors.

Comment: For the record, everything in JSON is a string. surround your Arrays and Objects with speech marks: `"`

Comment: In JSON, stuff wrapped in curly brackets { } is an object, and square brackets are arrays of multiple objects. Typically, if you serialize an Array(), it will produce [].

Comment: @KristyHughes I have updated my answer with my HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a fix.

Firstly, I noticed that in the beginning of you javascript, you parse the JSON response, restringify it, and tamper it. I think you shouldn't do that.

Just use the resulting object of the JSON parsing. You can get all the EnvIds by travelling the Shortcuts array. Here's some code.

```
function myFunction(response) {
    //here you were parsing, restringifying and tampering with the JSON. I removed the later parts.
    var obj = JSON.parse(response);

    var tbl = $("<table/>").attr("id", "mytable");
    $("#id01").append(tbl);

    //Here I travel through the "Shortcuts" table, to display all the EnvIds as you wanted.
    for (var i = 0; i < obj["Shortcuts"].length; i++) {
        var tr = "<tr>";
        var td1 = "<td>" + obj["Shortcuts"][i]["EnvId"] + "</td></tr>";
        $("#mytable").append(tr + td1);
    }

    // I removed this line. "out" is never defined. I do not know its purpose.
    //document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11o5ybtq/5/).

Answer (score 1):

Your codes have so many error as what you have posted.

For your query related to `{}` and `[]` bracket in Json string which define the Object and Object Array respectively.If you serialize Object that Json will wrap that into `{}` and serialization of List or Array of object will result in`[]`.

As per my understanding you need to parse your JSON and traverse through JsonObject to build your HTML, below code shows how to traverse `Shortcuts` Json Object Array and build the table for that.

Here is code :

```
function myFunction(response) 
{
       var arr = $.parseJSON(json);
       var jsonProfile = arr.Shortcuts;

       var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
       $("#id01").append(tbl);
       for(var i=0;i<jsonProfile.length;i++)
       {
          var tr="<tr>";
          var td1="<td>"+jsonProfile[i]["EnvId"]+"</td></tr>";
          $("#mytable").append(tr+td1); 
       }   
 }
```

Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(response) { 
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var Profile = arr.value[0].PROFILE;
    var jsonProfile = JSON.parse(Profile);
    var out = "<table>";
    for(var i=0;i<jsonProfile.Shortcuts.length;i++)
    {
       out += "<tr><td>" +
       jsonProfile.Shortcuts[i].EnvId +
       "</td></tr>";
    }  
    out += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

After going thru your answers, I was finally able to modify my code and it works fine now.